# issue with UINavigation back button work with "multi paged" parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I have two views **ViewA** and **ViewB**. From **ViewA**, I can navigate to **ViewB** through a table view cell select which is very common. My **ViewA** has a UIPageControl and several virtual pages so i can swap to select **Page1** or **Page2** in **ViewA** and navigate to **ViewB** accordingly(I set up properties of **ViewB** before view appears).

That works perfectly except one problem. Since it is a navigation based, and I do have a system provided back button. When I am at **ViewB** and navigate back to **ViewA**, it always loads **Page1**. Is there a way to dynamically navigate to different page of **ViewA** when the back button is tapped?

Thanks very much for reading my question.

Comment: Sorry I miss read your question, I've deleted my first answer below. In ViewA, do you set the pages in viewWillAppear? The view should not change when you pop the navigation controller.

Comment: Yes that's correct but I can do stuff on ViewB and that will effect which page I should be on ViewA and that's what I want to get. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, in that case I would use a delegate.

Comment: Yes andershqst, that would totally work if I put the delegate call in the ViewWillDisappear(). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view A's viewWillDisappear() function, save the currently displayed page (or it's number).
And then in viewWillDisappear(), check if a page has been saved, and then display the correct page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it would work, however that's probably too much if I have to actually save it to data storage. It is just a small thing nice to have but if that's too much we might not want it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may be a NSUserDefault

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: pageNum forKey: @"activePage"];